# Prove that $\|T\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1}|\langle x,T(x)\rangle|$.

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators

Let $T$ be a self adjoint bounded linear operator in a Hilbert space $H$. Prove that
$$\|T\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1}|\langle x,T(x)\rangle|$$

Comment: Have a look at this file page 12, Lemma 8.26 https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/book/ch8.pdf

Comment: I have no idea why this question is closed. It seems a perfectly fine question to me. Also, I do not understand the down votes for my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see the following rather self-contained proof:

[image]

Link: http://people.math.gatech.edu/~heil/6338/summer08/section5a_adjoint.pdf