# $S \in L(Y',X')$ is an adjoint operator iff $S'(X) \subseteq Y$, show $(i_X)' \circ i_{X'}= id_{X'}$

Tags: functional-analysis, adjoint-operators, dual-spaces

I'm studying Dirk Werner's functional analysis book and I'm stuck with one direction of the following problem in chapter III.4:

$S \in L(Y',X')$ is an adjoint operator iff $S'(X) \subset Y$ (in Lemma III.4.3 German version of the book).

One direction is done in the book:

$\Rightarrow: (T''(i_X(x)))(y') = (i_X(x))(T'y')=T'y'(x)=y'(Tx)= (i_Y(Tx))(y')$.

For the other direction, I read something online (can't find the source right now), that says, if I can prove the identity $(i_X)' \circ i_{X'} = id_{X'}$ then I could use it to do the following:
Let $S \in L(Y',X')$ be given and $S(X) \subset Y$. Then
$S = S \circ id_{X'} = (i_X)' \circ i_{X'} \circ S = (i_X)' \circ S'' \circ i_{Y'} = (S' \circ i_X)' \circ i_{Y'} =^{(*)} (i_Y \circ T) \circ i_{Y'} = T' \circ (i_Y)' \circ i_{Y'} = T' \circ id_{Y'} = T'$.

$(*)$:because of the requirements exists such a T

But I don't manage to proof that $(i_X)' \circ i_{X'}= id_{X'}$.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Not sure, but maybe this might help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1832836/a-linear-map-sy-to-x-is-weak-continuous-if-and-only-if-s-t-for-so

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately I don't see how this should help me.